# how to improve speed for azure event hub listener processing?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've set up an EventHub for APIM and I've created a listener (IEventProcessor) to capture context policy output.  It appears that the listener gets hit on an interval, maybe every 10-15 seconds.  Are there any approaches that you use to increase the speed at which events are processed by the IEventProcessor?  Are there any types of settings that push out messages more quickly or could this be achieved by scaling out the listeners to improve processing throughput?

Comment: Hey Greg.  It's great to see you are actively using API Management and the questions are great. Keep them coming.  However, if you could avoid asking the questions both here and on MSDN forums that would help us.  If we ever miss a question you have asked here, feel free to ping us via email at apimgmt@microsoft.com

Comment: thanks darrel will do

Answer (score 1):

We maintain an internal buffer before sending to EventHub and the flush happens every 15 seconds or when the buffer gets full (~ 256 Kb).

This has been done to use the EventHub in the best possible way
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/#batch-event-send-operations as essentially you are paying for it.

Let us know on the User Voice, if you would rather prefer more control via the policy configuration at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management

Comment: hi samir what if i'm using an event hub for scalability and I need to process messages as quickly as possible?  for example, if the user is saving an entity and the business wants to return the resulting order # as quickly as possible to real time?

Comment: @GregBrattle  We would be curious to hear more about how you are trying to use EventHub behind API Management?  I'm especially interested in how you are handling the event hub partitions.  If you wouldn't mind, could tell us a little more about your scenario, perhaps via email v-darmi@microsoft.com ?  Thanks.